# How do I render html tags (or new lines) within a variable?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

```
function Test() {
  let r = [ “hello\nworld”, “hi\nearth”]
  //r = r.map(rr => rr.replace(/\n/g, “<br/>”))
  return (
    <div>
      {r.map((a,i) => <div>{a}</div>)}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Can’t seem to get a new line to show up.

Answer (score 1):

It gets easier if you use `<p>` tags, which is often semantically more correct:

```js
function Test() {
  const r = [ "hello\nworld", "hi\nearth"];
  const paragraphs = r.split('\n').map( str => <p>{str}</p>);
  return (
    <div>
      {paragraphs}
    </div>
  )
}
```

But if you want `<br />` tags:

```js
function Test() {
  const r = [ "hello\nworld", "hi\nearth"];
  const elems = r[0];
  for(let ii = 1; ii < r.length; ii++) {
    elems.push(<br />, r[ii]);
  }
  return (
    <div>
      {elems}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To render the string containing html tags. You can do something like this.

```
function Test() {
  let r = [ “hello\nworld”, “hi\nearth”]
  //r = r.map(rr => rr.replace(/\n/g, “<br/>”))
  return (
    <div>
      {r.map((a,i) => <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: a }} />)}
    </div>
  )
}
```